# Writing a Pandas DataFrame object as MongoDB collection using a user defined function

Tags: mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I am using `pymongo` to insert a pandas dataframe (here it is `coll`) as collection to MongoDB database using the following code:

```
mongo_url = "mongodb://%s:%s" % (host, port) # not disclosed
client = pm.MongoClient(mongo_url)
db = client[dbname]
db.coll.insert_many(coll.to_dict('records'))
```

This works fine. But whenever I am trying to perform the same operation using a user defined function, though I am not getting any Python error, but the database is not updated. Below is my function:

```
def testWrite(host, port, dbname, coll):
    mongo_url = "mongodb://%s:%s" % (host, port) # not disclosed
    client = pm.MongoClient(mongo_url)
    db = client[dbname]
    db.coll.insert_many(coll.to_dict('records'))
    return 0
```

Here the `insert_many()` method is not working (i.e. not updating the database) without throwing any kind of error. Please suggest something so that I can pass the `dataframe` name in a function and push it to the database as a collection.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mongo DB, but don't you have to commit or to save / close your connection somehow?